# Unable to remove uchg user immutable flag/lock with root user

Tags: macos, permission, filesystem

General specs

| key | value |
| --- | --- |
| OS | macOS Monterey 12.6.3 |
| Application file | `/Applications/Falcon.app` |
| App appears in `/System/Applications/`? | No |

The application is some kind of antivirus distributed by [Crowdstrike](https://crowdstrike.com) that was installed before I inherited this computer. The [official uninstaller](https://www.crowdstrike.com/blog/tech-center/uninstall-protection-for-the-falcon-agent/) requires a "maintenance token", which I don't have. But I figure that, as an admin user account on this computer, I should have the ability to remove the app without having to authenticate inside the app itself.

Current app file permissions:

[image: file permissions]

When I run

```sh
# file location
cd /Applications

# show flags
ls -lO | grep <app>
# "drwxr-xr-x  3 root            wheel  uchg        96 Dec  1  2021 <app>.app"

# via sudo, fails
sudo chflags nouchg <app>.app

# via su, fails
su root
chflags nouchg <app>.app
```

I get

```
chflags: <app>.app: Operation not permitted
```

I've already tried disabling system integrity protection, and granting full disk access to Terminal, and changing file owner to myself.

```sh
csrutil status
# "System Integrity Protection status: disabled."

sudo chown <myself> <app>.app
# "chown: <app>.app: Operation not permitted"
```

**How do I unlock this file?**

Also posted at [discussions.apple.com](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254721556).

Comment: Please update the OP with the macOS version. Also, hiding the App name doesn't help us.

Comment: Anything that is root:wheel is inside the SSV.  You can't modify the SSV.

Comment: @MarcWilson Yeah that was my first thought, but would be good for OP to disclose which App so we know if it's in the SSV. May be in `/System/Applications` (that's SSV territory IIRC). There are `root:wheel` Apps in /Applications that can be `sudo rm -rf App.app` easily.

Comment: Added OS version and app info

Comment: When you say "inherited" - was the computer not "clean" -- i.e. factory state -- when you received? Is it ex office equipment (could have device management stuff on it.)? If I were you, I would erase all user content from System Preferences, and/or reinstall the OS.

Comment: Yes, it's a retired office computer, but don't want to reset/erase it for this if possible.